# Changing asterisk call-in directory recording?

Tags: asterisk, voip

I'm not sure what to call this, so I cannot Google it. When you call your Asterisk line and go to the directory, it asks you to enter the first three letters of your party's last name. When you do so, it plays a user-recorded sound file of the user saying their name. Like so:

```
"... or dial 3 for directory."
3
"Please enter the first three letters of your party's last name."
123
"'John Smith' - is this the correct person?"
```

How can I reset or change this recording so that the same extension can have a new greeting (i.e. `Joe Schmo` instead of `John Smith`)? I cannot find where Asterisk stores this sound file or how to tell it record a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FreePBX, Elastix (wich has FreePBX underneath) or another GUI to manage your PBX, you must have a Directory Application. You can map the extension number with the voicemail greeting, a TTS, spell the name, or playback a previously uploaded system recording.